# run nifi flow once and notify me when it is finish

Tags: apache-nifi

I use rest api in my program,I made a processor group for convent a mongodb collection to json file:
[image]
I want to run the scheduling only one time,so I set the "Run schedule" to 10000 sec.Then I will stop the group when the data flow have ran one time,and I made a Notify processor and add a DistributedMapCacheService.But the DistributedMapCacheClientService of the Notify processor only comunicates with the DistributedMapCacheService in nifi itself,It never nofity my program.

I try to use my own socket server,but I only get a message "nifi" but no more message.
My question is:If I only want scheduling run once and stop it,how do I know when shall I stop it?Or is there some other way to achieve my purpose,like detect if the json file exists or use incremental data(If the scheduling run twice,the data will be repeated twice)?

Comment: you can start your flow not by timer but with `HandleHttpRequest` and send response back with `HandleHttpResponse` when flow has finished (if flow runs fast). if flow in long then better to send async notification with `PutTCP`, `PostHTTP`, or `GetHTTP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @daggett said you can do it in a synchronous way you can use HandleHttpRequest as trigger and HandleHttpResponse to manage the response.
For an asynchronous was you have several options for the notification like PutTCP, PostHTTP, GetHTTP, use FTP, file system, XMPP or whatever.

If the scheduling run twice the duplicated elements depends on the processors you use, some of them have state others no, but if you are facing problems with repeated elements you can use the **DetectDuplicate** processor.